# How to create a reliable Installation Package for Windows in seconds?

Tags: windows, installer

I am looking a reliable way to create an Installation Package for a Unity 3D Video Game.

I have just tried NSIS (Nullsoft Scriptable Install System)
But the default user interface (of the final result) appear too much old.

If you have a better method (based on script) please give an advice!

Comment: 'Best' here is subjective. You need to define your idea of best to get a proper answer. As such, the question isn't suitable for GameDev.StackExchange. I'd update your question to define your requirements.